# Why Isn't My NodeJS Post Request Working? (From Django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, express, python-requests

I am trying to send a request that I'm receiving in my Django view to my expressjs api on the same server and I am either getting 500 errors or empty response bodies on the express end.

Here is my express.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('file-saver');
var app = express();
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'json/' });
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/example', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/example', async (req, res) => {
    await fs.saveAs(req.body, 'json.json');
    await console.log('Got body:', req.body);
    await res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen('8080', function () {
    console.log('Test');
});
```

Here is my django view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.http import FileResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
import json
from reportsappapi.utilities import logip
import requests

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def sendMail(request):
    url = 'https://example.com/example'
    clockout = request.FILES['clockout']
    clockoutJSON = json.load(clockout)
    x = request.post(url, clockout)
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `requests.post`? in plural? 
Are you sure you are able to get this code working without any syntax errors by the Python interpreter?

Comment: That's really nice of you to help me with such a stupid error. I've been reloading that server over and over trying to figure it out. I don't know how much longer I could have gone, sir!

Comment: Happens to all of us. 
Better to take a break, have a coffee and be back at it, if you are lost. 
I have found that it helps.

Comment: Oh brother I had something a bit more than a coffee. God bless. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Extra "s". as Arun pointed it out

Answer (score 0):

It should be
`x = requests.post(url, clockout)`
just like Arun T has said.
The request in use is the current server incoming request object and not the python request library.
You can as well use import alias, for example.

```
import requests as fetch
```

And then

```
x = fetch.post(url, clockout)`
```

To prevent common name errors